# How can I move to an external class without a navigation bar?

Tags: react-native

I can't find anything that doesn't use the navigation bar to load a new page. I just need a button that loads a new view like a segue (iOS) and loading a new Activity (Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better for you to make your question clearer, although I think I know what you are looking for.

Navigation in React-Native offers you segue, and activity transition. There are many options for you to choose, but lately [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) has been released, which is the future of RN navigation. So if you're starting fresh, learn to use it first.

However, [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) has a wider background with many PRs, support and everything you can think of about navigations has already been blended in it. Until React Navigation gets a bit maturer, you can choose to work with it easily.

Saying that, showing some code may help you understand how navigation works in RN, apart from navigating from navigation bar, as you stated.

You should first define your navigation tree, and give unique keys to each Scene (Activity, Segue) you have. Keys will help you navigate to those Scenes.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
        <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
        <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  }
}
```

Now we have Login, Register and Home scenes defined. Let's say you're in the login screen (You can simply add `initial={true}` to any scene that you would like to start your app with) and you'd like to navigate to Home screen. What you can do is simply importing *Actions* object from *react-native-router-flux* and navigate.

```
Actions.home() // Notice that home is your Home Scene key.
```

When this function is called, you immediately see a navigation, and a tabbar back button to get back. If you don't want to use back button (I guess this is your question in the first place), you can simply call

```
Actions.pop()
```

in your, lets say Touchable, to go back in your navigation stack.

Hope this answer gives you a head start. You can find a detailed documentation about react-native-router-flux [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md).

Comment: You said that a navigation, and a tabbar back button will appear, is there any way to hide these?

Comment: Yes. Add hideNavBar={true} to corresponding scene.